# Internal Server Error when I don't pass variables mentioned in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Internal Server Error is occurred when I don't pass all variable to .htaccess

**.htaccess code**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ Main.php?module=$1&work=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

According to above rule, it accepts three variables. If I pass a url like

```
http://example.com/main/var1/var2/var3
```

it works properly but when I don't pass the last one, it gives me **Internal Server Error**. Is there any method I can open 404 error for that or open the default thing in main.php ?

Comment: You can normally find the exact error message in the Apache error log. If you don't have full control on the server, you should have an alternative way to see logs (either a control panel or direct FTP download).

Answer (score 0):

You can check your three variables in `Main.php`, and if one or more is missing, do one of this things:

Redirect to "the default thing": http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Redirect to your 404-page. With the header() function (see link above) you can also send the HTTP-Status 404

Comment: It seems that error occuring in web server before Main.php execution.

Comment: yes. i m passing variable via htaccess to main.php thats why i can not check like that in main.php

Answer (score 0):

You must specify RewriteRule without last parameter and check its value inside code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ Main.php?module=$1&work=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ Main.php?module=$1&work=$2 [NC,L]
```

Also useful to create default RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ Main.php [L]
```

Inside code:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    ...
}
```

Comment: if i use default rule it will make all the links make to redirect at main.php even index page. and in above way if there are more then 3 variable i have to write that all times i was looking for a better way